# .sample seems to have a limited range

Tags: python

I have the below code which allows a user to choose the length of a password, if I enter something silly like 2049 it breaks can you please explain to me why?

```
with open("accounts.txt", 'a') as acc:
    length = int(input('\nEnter the length of password: '))
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    num = string.digits
    symbols = string.punctuation
    all = lower + upper + num + symbols
    temp = random.sample(all,length)
    password = "".join(temp)
    acc.write("{} {}\n".format(nu,password))
```

Comment: what does `nu` represents in `acc.write` line ?

Comment: size `2049` is very large as compare the size of all lowercases, uppercases and digits.

Comment: Take care using the name [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) for a variable. That's a built in function name. See how its highlighted red unlike all your other variables. Not a huge deal for a small sample program but worth being aware of.

Answer (score 1):

`sample(all, length)` returns a set of *unique* characters, so it's required that `length <= len(all)`. You want to use `random.choices` instead.

```
temp = random.choices(all, k=length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Program was crashing here `temp = random.sample(all,length)` when `length` is greater then `len(all)`.

Fix : generate the random manually `temp = [all[random.randint(0, len(all)-1)] for _ in range(length)]` and write it to file.

```
import string
import random

with open("accounts.txt", 'a') as acc:
    length = int(input('\nEnter the length of password: '))
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    num = string.digits
    symbols = string.punctuation
    _all = lower + upper + num + symbols
    #temp = random.choice(all,length)
    temp = [_all[random.randint(0, len(_all)-1)] for _ in range(length)]
    password = "".join(temp)
    #acc.write("{} {}\n".format(nu,password))
    acc.write(f"{password}")
```